# how to block torrent traffic on ubuntu server?

Tags: iptables, bittorrent, p2p

I want to block all P2P (including bittorrent) traffic going through my Ubuntu Server. I have tried :

1. Blocking certain strings, but it's not effective or user friendly
2. Blocking IPs that resolve to trackers, but it's impossible to keep pace with them so I need a more effective solution

What other options are there?

Answer (score -1):

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.100 --dport 1000:65010 -m time --timestart 05:00 --timestop 23:59 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -p udp -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.100 --dport 1000:65010 -m time --timestart 05:00 --timestop 23:59 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun -j DROP
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. If possible, you could elaborate a little more on it, so people can understand *why* they're doing what they're doing and how they can adapt this answer to their specific needs. Just edit your answer to do that.

Comment: why the timestamp and why the weekdays ?

Answer (score -2):

**Block torrents using iptables**

**Log Torrent**

```
iptables -N LOGDROP > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
iptables -F LOGDROP
iptables -A LOGDROP -j LOG --log-prefix "LOGDROP "
iptables -A LOGDROP -j DROP
```

**Block Torrent**

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "BitTorrent" -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "BitTorrent protocol" -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "peer_id=" -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string ".torrent" -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "announce.php?passkey=" -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "torrent" -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "announce" -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "info_hash" -j LOGDROP
```

**Block DHT keyword**

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "get_peers" --algo bm -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "announce_peer" --algo bm -j LOGDROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "find_node" --algo bm -j LOGDROP
```

**References**

[How to Block BitTorrent traffic on your Linux firewall](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-block-bittorrent-traffic-on-your-linux-firewall/)

[How to Block Bittorrent Traffic with IPtables](http://briansnelson.com/How_to_Block_Bittorrent_Traffic_with_IPtables)

Comment: -1 You're now blocking every (unencrypted) web site, e-mail, etc., that contains the word "torrent" or "announce". Equally, if an encryption/compression/base64 filter incidentally produces one of these byte sequences, the connection transferring its output is dropped.

Comment: not full solution. most torrents use encrypted ssl traffic, not able to track all of it. it's a hit and miss

for those facing this issue i advise xtables adddons